# Cors Origin specified, but wildcard is sent as response - NodeJS Express Cors()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, cors

I have a simple but annoying issue. I am running a nodejs server with `Apollo Server` for GraphQL and `express` for handling the web requests. I am setting a cookie after a successful login in redis via `express-session`

I do set the `origin` and the `credentials` options for `cors()`
However, on the front-end I still get the error message, that there is a wildcard in use.

If I changed the origin to `"http://localhost:3000/"` it would throw me the message, that it is not included in the origin list.

The cookie gets set:
[image]

The response also gives me:
[image]

When setting the credentials of createHTTPLink to `same-origin` no cookie is set. as per documentation (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/)

```
You just need to pass the credentials option. e.g. credentials: 'same-origin' as shown below, if your backend server is the same domain or else credentials: 'include' if your backend is a different domain.
```

Error Message:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

Node JS index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import Express from "express";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";

import session from "express-session";
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";
import {redis} from "./services/redis"
import cors from "cors"
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";

// load .env file
dotenv.config()

const main = async () => {
  await createConnection({
    name: "default",
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: [__dirname + "/modules/*/*.*"],

});

  // build the graphQL schema 
  // load all the resolvers!
  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [__dirname + "/modules/**/!(*.test).ts"],
  });

  // create the apollo server with the schema and make sure we have access
  // to req and res in context!
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({req, res} : any) => ({req, res})
  });

  // initialise Express itself
  const app = Express();

  // add the cors for the react frontend
  app.use(cors({
      credentials: true, 
      origin: "http://localhost:3000"
  }))

  // create the redis connection
  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)


  // setup the redis session 
  const redisSessionStore = session({
    store: new RedisStore({
      client: redis as any,
    }),
    name: process.env.COOKIE_NAME,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1 * 365, // 1 year
    },
  } as any)

  // make sure redis is used before we mix with apollo
  app.use(redisSessionStore);

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

  // start the server
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Started on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/graphql`);
  });
};

main();
```

React JS Front-End

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";


const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  credentials: 'include'
})


const client = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

export default client;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to actually set the corsOptions on the Apollo Server configuration.

```
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: corsOptions });
```